# Unable to push image to GCR from Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, google-container-registry

I am running a VM in google cloud that runs a Jenkins server (within a docker container). I am trying to build a Docker image for my application and push it out to Google Container Registry using Jenkins pipeline.

1. I installed all the required Jenkins plugins:
   Google OAuth Credentials Plugin,
   Docker Pipeline Plugin,
   Google Container Registry Auth Plugin
2. Created a service account + key with Storage Admin and Object Viewer roles. Downloaded the json file.
3. Created a credential in Jenkins using the google project name as the id and the json key.
4. My pipeline code for build looks like this:

   ```
   stage('Build Image') {
       app = docker.build("<gcp-project-id>/<myproject>")
   }
   ```
5. My pipeline code for build looks like this:

   ```
   stage('Push Image') {
   docker.withRegistry('https://us.gcr.io', 'gcr:<gcp-project-id>') {
       app.push("${commit_id}")
       app.push("latest")
   }
   ```

   }

However, the build fails at the last step with this error:

```
unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication
```

I have spent several hours trying to figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Create a service account in GCP with permission to push image and then copy the credential json fie and save it as credentials inside Jenkins; call in the credentials id inside your pipeline like below and it should push images to gcr

```js
            withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'gcr', variable: 'GC_KEY')]){
              sh "cat '$GC_KEY' | docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://eu.gcr.io"
              sh "gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file='$GC_KEY'"
              sh "gcloud auth configure-docker"
              GLOUD_AUTH = sh (
                    script: 'gcloud auth print-access-token',
                    returnStdout: true
                ).trim()
              echo "Pushing image To GCR"
              sh "docker push eu.gcr.io/${google_projectname}/${image_name}:${image-tag}"
          }
```

Additionally i have defined some variables used above

Answer (score 2):

I have an identical problem. I found out that Jenkins doesn't seem to use those credentials: Under usage it says 'This credential has not been recorded as used anywhere.' . When used with gcloud util, the service account and key work fine, so the problem is somewhere in Jenkins.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please share your code snippet to show the build and push steps? I am running Jenkins as a Docker container on a GCP machine.

Comment: Thank you. I had to add a docker login step for this to work. The google auth plugin does not work at all.

Comment: Confirmed. I too got it working with an additional docker login step. No luck with the plugin.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to add details of the docker login step as an answer in case other are having issue with this?

Answer (score 0):

key id must be exact **google-container-registry**

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {nodejs "node"}
    environment {
        CI = 'true'
        PROJECT_ID = 'projet-marshmallow'
        CLUSTER_NAME = 'cluster-1'
        LOCATION = 'us-central1-c'
        CREDENTIALS_ID = 'kubernetes'
        DOCKER_FILE_PATH="${FOLDER_NAME}/Dockerfile"
        SERVICE_NAME='users'
        FOLDER_NAME='prod-config'
        K8_FILE_PATH="${FOLDER_NAME}/k8.yaml"
        IMAGE_TAG = "us.gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/${SERVICE_NAME}:${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
    }
    
    stages {
        stage('Scm Checkout') {
            steps {
                checkout scm
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                dir("${SERVICE_NAME}/"){
                  sh 'npm install'
                }
            }
        }
        
        stage('Build Docker Image') {
            steps {
                sh 'whoami'
                script {
                    dockerImage = docker.build("${IMAGE_TAG}","-f ${SERVICE_NAME}/${DOCKER_FILE_PATH} ${SERVICE_NAME}")
                }
            }
        }
        

        stage("Push Docker Image") {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo "Push Docker Image"
                    docker.withRegistry('https://us.gcr.io', "gcr:google-container-registry") {
                    dockerImage.push()
                }
                    
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Change image version') {
            steps {
                dir("${SERVICE_NAME}/prod-config"){
                  sh """
                    cat k8.yaml | grep image
                    sed -i 's|image: .*|image: "${IMAGE_TAG}"|' k8.yaml
                    cat k8.yaml | grep image
                    """
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy to K8s') {
            steps{
                echo "Deployment started ..."
                sh 'ls -ltr'
                sh 'pwd'
                echo "Start deployment of ${SERVICE_NAME} service."
                step([
                    $class: 'KubernetesEngineBuilder',
                    projectId: env.PROJECT_ID, 
                    clusterName: env.CLUSTER_NAME, 
                    location: env.LOCATION, 
                    manifestPattern: "${SERVICE_NAME}/${K8_FILE_PATH}",
                    credentialsId: env.CREDENTIALS_ID, 
                    // verifyDeployments: true 
                 ])
                echo "Deployment Finished ..."
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
           echo "Deleting docker iamge ..."
           sh "docker rmi -f ${IMAGE_TAG}"

        }
        success {     
            emailext body: "${currentBuild.currentResult}: Job ${env.JOB_NAME} build ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}\n More info at: ${env.BUILD_URL}",
                recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider'], [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']],
                subject: "Jenkins Build ${currentBuild.currentResult}: Job ${env.JOB_NAME}"
        }
        failure {  
            emailext body: "${currentBuild.currentResult}: Job ${env.JOB_NAME} build ${env.BUILD_NUMBER}\n More info at: ${env.BUILD_URL}",
                recipientProviders: [[$class: 'DevelopersRecipientProvider'], [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']],
                subject: "Jenkins Build ${currentBuild.currentResult}: Job ${env.JOB_NAME}"
        }
    }
}
```